# Linq select in query in c#

Tags: linq, list, linq-to-entities, selector

I have two lists containing data.

```
List<changeLogUsers> users;

UserID


List<changeLogQualifications> userQualifications;

UserID
QualificationID
```

I want to select only those userQualifications for which UserID is available in users list.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This thread may be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187996/intersect-two-list-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = userQualifications.Where(u => users.Any(x => x.UserID == u.UserID));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<changeLogQualifications> userQualifications.Select(p=>p.UserID!=null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or alternatively:

```
var results = from uq in userQualifications
              join u in users on uq.UserID equals u.UserID
              select uq;
```