# Get identical elements in two lists with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm pretty novice with LINQ, and I usually use only `Where()` function.

Let's suppose that I have two lists with objects of the same type, `l1` and `l2`.

My actual code looks like this :

```
int i, j;
for (int i = 0; i < l1.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < l2.Count; j++)
    {
        if (l1[i].Equals(l2[j]))
        {
            //Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I have the feeling that I can improve my code with LINQ, by getting all "duplicate" elements in `l1` **and** `l2`. Have you any idea of how ?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Use Intersect() ; Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187996/intersect-two-list-in-c-sharp

Comment: @MickaelV. That's it, I used the wrong keyword. *Intersection* is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you.