# intersection of two list add to another list in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, list, asp.net-identity

I have following lists

```
List<AspNetUser> approverprofiles = db.AspNetUsers.Where(w => w.Subsidary_ID =="04").ToList();

List<AspNetRole> approverusers = db.AspNetRoles.Where(w => w.Name == "Approver").ToList();
```

`approverprofiles` is a `AspNetUser` LIST and `approverusers` is a `AspNetRole` LIST , how can I merge or add these two lists into one list ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187996/intersect-two-list-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of merging or adding, you can serialize it into one class as-

```
Public Class MergeClass {

  public List<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers {get;set;}
  public List<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles {get;set;}

}
```

Now-

```
var mergeList= new MergeClass {
  AspNetUsers= approverprofiles.ToList(),
  AspNetRoles=  approverusers.ToList()
}
```

**Edit**

As far as adding an object to the existing class is simple

```
Public Class MergeClass {

  public List<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers {get;set;}
  public List<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles {get;set;}
  public string MyObject {get;set;}
}
```

You can then use it-

```
  var mergeList= new MergeClass {
      AspNetUsers= approverprofiles.ToList(),
      AspNetRoles=  approverusers.ToList(),
      MyObject= "someString"
  }
```

Accessing the properties-

```
var aspNetUsersFromMergedList = MergeClass.AspNetUsers.Select(a=>a.Id))
```

As per you problem with loop , you can access a property like this-

```
foreach(var approvermail in MergeClass.AspNetUsers.ToList(){
   //do something
}
```

Comment: but then how to add objects to this new `mergeList` ??

Comment: another question popup here once I use your approach. I have a loop like this `foreach (var approvermail in mergeList){`  but here I'm getting this error `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'project_namea.Models.MergeClass' because 'project_name.Models.MergeClass' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: @kez, have you given public access to `MergeClass` properties?

Comment: `public class MergeClass {public List<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; } public List<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }}` 
yes I defined it as like this , what else should I do ?

Comment: pardon me you understood it wrong way, could be my explaining mistake, I want to add objects that getting from `List<AspNetUser> approverprofiles = db.AspNetUsers.Where(w => w.Subsidary_ID =="04").ToList();` and `List<AspNetRole> approverusers = db.AspNetRoles.Where(w => w.Name == "Approver").ToList();`

Comment: let me know , whether you got my idea ?

Comment: to add objects? where do you want to add the objects? to these two lists?

Comment: pardon me again I meant results that I'm getting through this line `List<AspNetUser> approverprofiles = db.AspNetUsers.Where(w => w.Subsidary_ID =="04").ToList();` and this line `List<AspNetRole> approverusers = db.AspNetRoles.Where(w => w.Name == "Approver").ToList();`

Comment: How to put those two results into this new list ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102661/discussion-between-manoz-and-kez).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
approverprofiles = approverprofiles .Concat(approverusers ).ToList();
```

`Concat` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` that is the two lists put together, it doesn't modify either existing list. Also, since it returns an IEnumerable, if you want to assign it to a variable that is `List<T>,` you'll have to call `ToList()` on the `IEnumerable<T>` that is returned.

or You can try

```
approverprofiles.AddRange(approverusers)
```

Comment: How can you? can you add or concat 2 different tables?
can you give me reference please?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<AspNetUser> approverprofiles = db.AspNetUsers.Where(w => w.Subsidary_ID =="04").ToList();

List<AspNetRole> approverusers = db.AspNetRoles.Where(w => w.Name == "Approver").ToList();

approverprofiles.AddRange(approverusers);
```

Comment: these list types are different. It must fail

Answer (score 0):

Use below inbuilt function to add second list to first list.

```
approverprofiles.AddRange(approverusers);
```