# How to optimize string search in two very large lists

Tags: c#, string

I have two list of strings:

```
private List<string> sortedList; //about 150k items
private List<string> mixedList; // about 200k items
```

One of them is *sorted*, the other one is not.

I use the following code to ***find the intersecting words***:

```
List<string> intersectingWords=new List<string>();
StringInvariantComparer stringComparer = new StringInvariantComparer();

foreach (var item in mixedList)
{
  int res = sortedList.BinarySearch(item, stringComparer);
  if (res >= 0 && !intersectingWords.Contains(item))
    intersectingWords.Add(item);
}



public class StringInvariantComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return string.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it takes about 20-25 seconds which is way too much time.

If I change the `StringComparison` type to `Ordinal`, it finishes in 1-2 seconds *but can't find 30% of the words*.

What would you recommend to optimize the code?

**UPDATE**:

If I use the following code:

```
var wrongRes = sortedList.Intersect(mixedList).ToList();
```

The result:

[image]

If I use the following code:

```
var upperMixed = new List<string>();
var upperSorted = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in mixedList)
    upperMixed.Add(item.ToUpper());
foreach (var item in sortedList)
    upperSorted.Add(item.ToUpper());
foreach (var word in upperSorted.Intersect(upperMixed))
{
    intersectingWords.Add(word.ToLower());
}
```

The result:

[image]

They are clearly not the same :)

Comment: A binary search algorithm has O (Log N) I think...better than O (N)

Comment: Clearly you've seen questions on "intersection of two lists" (i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187996/intersect-two-lists-in-c-sharp) but decided to do something different for some reason. Could you please spell out the reason and provide sample that shows words that can't be found by versions of ordinal comparison (casesensitive/caseinsensitive)? (i.e. do you care about `ß` vs `ss`)

Comment: Would a `Parallel.ForEach` help?

Comment: @BrunoLM  no - parallel is not a cure for picking wrong algoritm (O(n^2) vs. O(n)).

Comment: I would sort the *mixedList*, and then *merge* two lists.. (only 1 pass on both lists)

Comment: To resume all comments : ```var intersectingWords = new HashSet<string>(mixedList.AsParallel().Where(item => sortedList.BinarySearch(item, stringComparer) >= 0));```

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace `List<string> intersectingWords` with `HashSet<string> intersectingWords` - it's better for `Contains` operations.
2. Prepare words: keep in `sortedList` and `mixedList` strings in uppercase and use `Ordinal` comapre. If you need original strings, you can keep structure of 2 words (normal and uppercase). Compare uppercase and add normal word in `intersectingWords`

Comment: Uppercasing is rarely enough to normalize all text... Plus HashSet using OrdinalIgnoreCase comparer would do the same without extra effort....

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov What do you mean by not enough? In my case, the Ordinal method worked with uppercased words. What should I expect?

Comment: @Nestor There are letters outside ASCII range - so while you say InvariantIgnoreCase worked for particular sample it is not clear if it is actually enough for you or there are more words i.e. do you care about ß vs ss, what about use of denormalized ascents?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I updated the initial post. I get strange results, if I use the built-in comparer. If I uppercase the words, it works okay. The sorted list comes from a file. Could be an encoding issue?