# C# 2 List with Matching Records

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 List of dates.

```
List<DateTime> 1st;
List<DateTime> 2nd;
```

I want a count of matching dates within this 2 dates.
I can use the foreach logic & get the results.

But what is the easiest way of achieving this?

Comment: Before asking "what is the easiest way" just show what is *your* way. You have to provide some own idea in order to get help here, We´re not doing your work. In particular you should define what you consider "easy". Only few lines of code? Without any framework-code? Without ...?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have already noted the `foreach` logic in the question. Few will be there who doesn't know simple 'foreach' logic, so i didn't pasted the code.

Comment: And why doesn´t this suffice your needs? It´s obviously easy (as you noted only a few don´t know the simple logic of `foreach`) and does its job. Why need another (possibly more difficult) approach? What you consider easy is purely opinionated.

Comment: @HimBromBeere There is a big difference between easy & smart coding. I am not an expert in coding but i like to code it in a smarter way.

Comment: Making your question not a bit less opiniated, as smart is also quite fuzzy. I assume you´re looking for a linq-oneliner as V319 provided one. But that is neither "faster" nor "consumes less memory", it´s just "shorter".

Comment: It is obvious that you don't have the answer for this question. Rather than fooling someones answer you can better find some questions which you know the answer for. 
This question carries the possibility for creative solutions which can help others in future.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Linq;
1st.Intersect(2nd).Count();
```

This should work.

Also you can make inner join using linq

Comment: While this is a correct answer, OP should have spent some effort coming up with their own solution first.

Comment: Beware of comparing dates using the default IEqualityComparer... the 2 DateTime will have to be equivalent to the ten-thousandth of a second: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx.  Consider passing in your own IEqualityComparer.

Comment: Not to mention this is basically a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187996/intersect-two-lists-in-c-sharp