# Remove columns from DataTable which are not in List<string>

Tags: c#, list

We have this `List<string>`

```
List<string> A = ['a','b','c']
```

And another `Datatable [B]` with the following columns

```
'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' // the columns of DataTable B
```

How do we *remove* all of the columns **which are not found** in `List<string>` A from `Datatable B`?

Comment: Intersection of two list. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7188030/2845389

Comment: @Kaushik I couldn't understand from the answer how to achieve this... can you give an example with the list of string and datatable specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove all the columns not found in list 'A'

```
var A = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
var toRemove = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).Except(A).ToList();

foreach (var col in toRemove) dt.Columns.Remove(col);
```

Comment: Thanks, I get a "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" error...

Comment: @levi Try adding `.ToList()` to copy the value, will update answer

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a simple `for` loop:

```
  DataTable table = new DataTable();

  table.Columns.Add("a", typeof(string));
  table.Columns.Add("b", typeof(string));
  table.Columns.Add("C", typeof(string));
  table.Columns.Add("d", typeof(string));
  table.Columns.Add("e", typeof(string));
  table.Columns.Add("F", typeof(string));

  var A = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };

  // HashSet is a better collection in the context:
  //  1. We can specify comparer (e.g. we can ignore case)
  //  2. It's faster if the collection has many items
  // Sure, you can put A.Contains instead of columnsToKeep.Contains
  HashSet<string> columnsToKeep = 
    new HashSet<string>(A, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  // For i-th column we should either either keep column (do nothing) or remove it
  for (int i = table.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    if (!columnsToKeep.Contains(table.Columns[i].ColumnName))
      table.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
int numCols = dt.Columns.Count;

foreach(String str in A){//loop all strings in arrays

 for(int i=0;i<numCols;i++){//loop all columnames in dataTable B
      string columnName =dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();//get column Name
      //check if columnNames in B are equal to 
      if(!str.Equals(columnName){
        //remove column
         dt.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
      }else{
       //column name is equal to the string array
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ive edited my answer, feel free to approach and give the output

Comment: I think it should be

 string columnName = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
 List<string> A = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("a");
            dt.Columns.Add("b");
            dt.Columns.Add("c");
            dt.Columns.Add("d");
            dt.Columns.Add("e");
            foreach (string col in A)
            {
                dt.Columns.Remove(col);
            }
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                WriteLine(column.ColumnName);
                WriteLine(" ");
            }
```

Comment: The question is not how to remove the columns in the list (a), it's how to keep only them...