# Better design pattern to compare two lists

Tags: c#, design-patterns

i need a suggestion for the scenario noted below :

Contents in List A : string name , byte[] ,etc

Contents in List B  : string name.

i have two collections  and i need to iterate the List A with List B and check in a sequence if name from List B == name from List A .

for this i do a while loop with the sequence lengths and if /else loop for decision making if name matches or not.

i have to take decisions and other processing things for each match/unmatch item in list , also the two lists are not guaranteed of same size

is there any better way to avoid loops and if/else?

Comment: There is an `Intersect` method from `System.Linq`, have a look at existing thread [Intersect Two Lists in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187996/intersect-two-lists-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Are you looking for a way to make the code more concise or more efficient?

Comment: to be more readable and efficient

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Zip` function of Enumerable after building a projection:

```
ListA.Select(a => a.name).Zip(ListB, (a, b) => a == b)
```

at the end you have a list of booleans and you could use `Any` to find if all items match:

```
ListA.Select(a => a.name).Zip(ListB, (a, b) => a == b).Where(r => r).Any()
```

Comment: i have to take decisions and other processing for each match/unmatch item in list , also the two lists are not guaranteed of same size

Answer (score 0):

Using dictionary will solve performance issue.